# Firewall Being turned off

Tags: macos, security, firewall

Is it possible for an application to close my OSX firewall? Several times I have opened the security pref and I find FireWall off while I do not remember turning it off. For antivirus I use ClamXav which doesnt have a firewall so it should not be it... `Is there a way to check if some application is closing the firewall ?`

Answer (score 1):

Check /Applications/Utilities/Console.app after the firewall is turned off.
There might be a message about the change.

Answer (score 1):

If you give an application your administrative password (during e.g. a software installation or update) it can indeed change your system settings. An application running on the system that have been granted administrative rights can also turn it off. Try turning the firewall on, rebooting the machine, and see if it’s then turned off when you boot it. Should help troubleshoot if it’s a local program that causes this.

I’d actually suspect that you do it yourself or someone else who have access to the machine does it. In any case, had Apple [enabled the firewall by default](https://www.aeyoun.com/opinion/mac-default-firewall-state.html) you could be more certain that either you, a piece of local software, or another user is turning it off for you.

As for [ClamXav](http://www.clamxav.com), it does not provide a competing firewall service nor does it have any interest in disabling your firewall. Nor would any code-signed application (from the Mac App Store or signed using an Apple Trusted Certificate from the wider internet) have any incentive for turning off the firewall. These applications are given access automatically, so they would not need to interfere  with it either.